# Application cache and local storage

Tags: html, pdf, caching, local-storage, html5-appcache

I need some help architecting a new application.

The gist of it is that we will have a web-based application that serves up PDF's that are quite large in nature, anywhere from 2mb to 100mb. This will be an intranet (not internet) application with hundreds of users. The users will view the PDF's inline (i.e. embedded in the web page), alongside a custom navigation. Clicking on navigation links will load different PDF's in the viewer panel (no, PDF bookmarks don't solve the same problem in this case).

The viewer part is easier -- just embed it in an iframe, or Acrobat, or pdf.js, etc.

(This is a good visual example of what we're getting at: http://partstore.agriculture.newholland.com/us/parts-search.html#epc::mr48569ar123471 -- no we don't see tractor parts! But it's similar to the functionality.)

The main things we're worried about is a) traffic. Loading/reloading large PDF's across the network every time will consume unnecessary resources. b) It needs to work offline for pre-cached content. A user could download/cache hundreds of PDF's. It looks like the new features of HTML5 will help immensely here.

So, I started to look at Application Cache to cache the application files. I'm aware of some of the shortcomings of this, but it's the obvious route. But it seems you must explicitly declare the files you want to cache. That's great for application files or if every user cached the same stuff. But a user should be able to click "pre-load these 500 PDF's so that I can look at them offline". That gets outside of app cache manifest.

So I'm looking at localStorage options but it's unclear to me just *how* I could leverage that. A user needs to pre-load hundreds of PDF's. While online, the app should pull them down from the server and then the app reference the cached versions while offline -- or even online if the PDF on the server hasn't been updated recently. What API's should I look at? How will this play nice with Application Cache?

As an aside, our corporate standards are both IE11 and Chrome (currently v50). It's fine to force one or the other. And my understanding of local Storage is that the app must request unlimited storage (see here https://developer.chrome.com/apps/offline_storage). That is also fine, but I'm unclear if I need to create a formal Chrome app?

The nearest example I can think of is Google Drive. Somehow it loads the docs/spreadsheets/etc. offline so that if you visit drive.google.com disconnected from the internet, those files load. Yet those files are dynamic and clearly not in the cache manifest (right?). How does Google Drive store these dynamic files offline, and how does the application know to load it from cache/local storage instead of from the Internet?

And, in contrast, would I run into any issues with binary data like a PDF?

Thoughts appreciated!

Thanks
Tom

Comment: You can use [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) -- there is no limits as in localStorage . Check also Service Workers and stuff at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Fundamentals/Offline.

Comment: @async5 thanks! that is helpful, esp. the diagram. 1)  i have only chrome and IE11 to work with, not firefox. will i need to make a chrome app, or will a "open web app" suffice? 2) where are you getting the idea that IndexedDB has no storage limits (documentation)? does the app need to request this storage? does the data persist? is this true for chrome, too?

Comment: There are limits for IndexedDB, but browser will/may prompt a user when more storage is required. See https://developer.chrome.com/apps/offline_storage for more details. See also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh673548(v=vs.85).aspx